# Sbt Plugin, Default File SettingKey

Tags: sbt

I have a settingKey that I have defined in project/build.scala

```
val databasePropertiesFile = settingKey[File]("The file we use to grab the database login configuration.")
```

And I want to assign it a default value based on the sourceDirctory, something like this, but it doesn't compile:

```
  databasePropertiesFile := {
    sourceDirectory / "db/devel.properties"
  }
```

What is the magic I must perform to set a default File?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic is ".value":

```scala
databasePropertiesFile := {
  sourceDirectory.value / "db" / "devel.properties"
}
```

Comment: My issue was that IntelliJ complains about this syntax.  I can compile in sbt directly.